# How to signal EOF to node.js stdin from console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple node.js app to echo stdin.  When I run it interactively on the Windows console, I expected control-Z to be recognised as an EOF signal.  But it isn't.  So how do I get a node app to treat control-Z as EOF?

```
// testEcho.js

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
console.log("input is a TTY?:",process.stdin.isTTY);

process.stdin.on('readable',function() {
    var vText = process.stdin.read();
    if (vText != null)
        console.log('echo: "%s"',vText);
    process.stdout.write('> '); // prompt for next
    });

process.stdin.on('end',function() { // Works for redirected input but not triggered by ^Z on TTY
    console.log('end of input reached');
    });
```

```

Comment: `process.on("SIGINT", fn);`

Comment: My experience with node 4.8.2 on debian is that process.stdin emits both 'end' and 'close' when ctrl-D is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear the solution is to use `readline`.  This is more terminal-aware, and treats an interactive TTY ctrl-D as EOF, while also handling redirected input streams correctly.  Also, being line oriented/aware, it conveniently strips newlines from the input strings.

```
var readline = require('readline');
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
console.log("input is a TTY?",process.stdin.isTTY);

var rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});
rl.setPrompt('> ');
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line' ,function(aText) { console.log('echo: "%s"',aText); rl.prompt(); });
rl.on('close',function()      { console.log('input has closed'); /* ... */ });
```

Comment: It's notable that ctrl-D (not ctrl-Z) is recognised as EOF on Windows, but that's fine by me.  Ctrl-D is ASCII EOT after all.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Cygwin, tried sending Ctrl+D, but NodeJS doesn't react using readline.

Answer (score 7):

the problem is you're using `process.stdin.on` instead of `process.on()`

See the fix I made here and everything should be fine and dandy :) Enjoy!

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
console.log("input is a TTY?:", process.stdin.isTTY);

process.stdin.on('readable',function() {
    var vText = process.stdin.read();
    if (vText != null)
        console.log('echo: "%s"',vText);
    process.stdout.write('> '); // prompt for next
});

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  console.log('Over and Out!');
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Also I replaced `'end'` with `'SIGINT'` as that's the signal that is caught by `CTRL+C`

You can read about the signal events here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately control-C terminates the process, whereas I'm only trying to signal end of input, without necessarily stopping the process.

Comment: @MichaelLemaire: ctrl-C kills the process if you don't have a handler for `SIGINT`. Once you install a handler like the above ctrl-C no longer kills the process. Which is why the example above includes `process.exit()` if you comment out that line the process wouldn't be killed.

Comment: @MichaelLemaire Comment out `process.exit(0);`

Comment: There is a massive semantic difference between EOF and SIGINT.  I am not interested in SIGINT.  I want to handle interactive TTY EOF, which is typically signalled by ctrl-D on unixen and ctrl-Z on Windows.  It has a completely different meaning and purpose than SIGINT.  Perhaps my example code has caused confusion by having the 'end' function output "goodbye".  It could in fact be doing anything, e.g. starting to process the data that was entered prior to EOF.

Comment: @MichaelLemaire Sorry for the misunderstanding, I don't believe it is possible to set a listener for EOF. :(

Comment: @MichaelLemaire - this is kind a pragmatic approach but you could look for an input line that consists only of 1a 0d 0a - Windows requires a CR-LF combination to recognize the ^Z anyway.

Comment: There's some way to use the  process.stdout.write('> '); // prompt for next in MS-DOS Node script? I'm having some problems with ffmpeg end process and that could be the solution to my problem.